# How to make calculations with counters?

Tags: counters, calculations, totcount

I have three counters `counterBoat`, `counterThink` and `counterWork`.

I want to print the integer `"round"(100*counterBoat/(counterBoat+ counterThink+ counterWork))` in my document.

I use the package `totcount`.

Comment: Load the `xfp` package and use `\inteval`, and use `\value` to access the values of the counters. The result is rounded by default. `\inteval{100*\value{counterBoat}/(\value{counterBoat}+\value{counterThink}+\value{counterWork})}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 \numexpr(100*\value{counterBoat}) / 
        ( \value{counterBoat} + \value{counterThink} + \value{counterWork})\relax
```

Comment: Just +1 for not using unneeded packages... My  previous comment about lost parenthesis was no valid ... was a combination of edited and non edited answer ... Sorry.

Comment: If you want to print that number rather than use it in another calculation, prefix with `\the`

Comment: @koleygr your comment was valid until (literally) a second before you posted it, so no need to apologise!

Comment: Thanks David ... Have a nice afternoon...

Comment: Thanks David. Can you give an example where this number is printed? Thanks

Comment: @Colas as I say just put `\the` in front of that line in a document and the number will be printed. There is no testable code in this answer as you did not supply a test document in the question.

Comment: Thanks, I have an error but it is unrelated (it is a division by 0).

Comment: Since I use `totcount`, the command to get the counter is `\total{counterBoat}`. With your code, replacing `\value` by `\total` leads to an error.

Comment: `\totvalue` might make it... I'll test

Comment: David, the following does not compile: `\the\numexpr(100*\totvalue{counterBoat}) / (0.1 +\totvalue{counterBoat} + \totvalue{counterThink} + \totvalue{counterWork})\relax` because of the `0.1`. Could you help me? Thanks

Comment: @Colas of course not, you are using `\numexpr` and counters so this is integer arithmetic. That appears to be a completely different question, perhaps you want to use the xfp package and floating point arithmetic, i really can't guess.

Comment: @Colas also your question in the comment about `\total` also appears to be a different question. For _any_ latex counter no matter which package allocated it, `\value` will access its value. You asked about latex counters.  `\total` is presumably a package command that calculates a total, you can't use such a thing inline in an expression.

Comment: Thanks David, I wanted to avoid the division by zero by a trick.

Comment: Yes David it is from the package totcount

Comment: as you said, but the way the site works, you post answers to the question as posted. the question asks how to evaluate that expression given three latex counters and that's what this answer does.  If you want to ask a new question about `\total` ask a new question but this time construct it properly with a proper test file. Without that I wouldn't even guess how you want to change this answer.